# targetSdkVersion in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-version

I have the targetSdkVersion set as 17 in my manifest. Kindly let me know if there will be any problem when I run this in the phone which has the API of 18.

### Manifest xml :

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will not support API 18 and if you upload it to [play store](http://play.google.com/store/apps)
then it will not be visible for all device > API 17

For example my Application which is uploaded to Play Store have 10 - 18 API support
so it support 3326 Type of  devices on play store similarly and it is available for those api level devices only

### My app on PlayStore

[image: My App support]

### Permissions also matters

Say if you want Wifi Permissions and device not have wifi it won't be visible for those device who don't have wifi
[image]

If you directly install it to Device > API 17 it will give warning but will install

[The Official Documentation Mentions here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)):

> To maintain your application along with each Android release, you should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding platform version.

Answer (score 0):

No. But it is recommended to set android:targetSdkVersion to the newest version.